# ReactJS and Typescript - Children components : get children props and refresh children when parent state changed

Tags: reactjs, typescript, validation

I need help on ReactJS and Typescript code, with the use of material-ui.

I want to redo the tab system proposed on the following link by creating my own component names: https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/#simple-tabs.

Here is the code I made: https://codepen.io/Answerrer/pen/wvKLLzg.

```
interface MyTabPanelProperties {
  label: string;
  value: number;
  index: number;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}

 type MyTabPanelState = {}

class MyTabPanel extends React.Component<MyTabPanelProperties, MyTabPanelState> {

  render(): JSX.Element {
    const { children, value, index } = this.props;
    const element = (
      <div role="tabpanel" hidden={value !== index} aria-labelledby={'simple-tab'}>
        {children}
      </div>
    );

    return element;
  }
}

interface MyTabsProperties<T = MyTabPanelProperties> {
  value?: number;
  children: React.ReactElement<T> | Array<React.ReactElement<T>> | React.Component<T> | Array<React.Component<T>>;
}

interface MyTabsState {
  value: number;
}

class MyTabs extends React.Component<MyTabsProperties, MyTabsState> {
  constructor(props: MyTabsProperties) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: this.props.value ? this.props.value : 0
    };
  }

  private checkChildrenName(children: ReactNode, names: string | Array<string>): boolean {
    const childs = React.Children.toArray(children);
    let check = false,
        allNames = new Array<string>();

    if (names instanceof Array) {
      allNames = names;
    } else {
      allNames = names.split(' ');
    }

    if (allNames.length === 0) {
      throw Error('Must specify names for check children');
    }

    check = childs.every((child) => {
      let check = false;
      const name = this.getComponentChildName(child);
      if (name) {
        check = allNames.includes(name);
      }
      return check;
    });

    return check;
  }

  private getComponentChildName(component: any): string | undefined {
    const type = (component.type || {});
    let name = undefined;

    if (component) {
      name = component.displayName ||
      component.name ||
      type.displayName ||
      type.name ||
      undefined;
    }

    return name;
  }

  render(): JSX.Element {
    const { children } = this.props;
    let element: JSX.Element;
    if (this.checkChildrenName(children, 'MyTabPanel')) {
      element = (
        <div>
          <AppBar position='static'>
            <Tabs value='0' onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>
              {React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => {
                return this.renderAppBarTab(child, index);
              })}
            </Tabs>
          </AppBar>
          {children}
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      throw Error('Must use MyTabPanel component in a MyTabs component');
    }
    return element;
  }

  private handleChange(event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, newValue: number): void {}

  private renderAppBarTab(child, index: number): JSX.Element {
    const label = 'Test';
    const element = (
      <Tab label={label} key={index} />
    );

    return element;
  }

  set value(value:number) {
    this.setState({value: value});
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <MyTabs>
      <MyTabPanel label='Tab1'>
        <Typography>Test1</Typography>
      </MyTabPanel>
      <MyTabPanel label='Tab2'>
        <Typography>Test2</Typography>
      </MyTabPanel>
    </MyTabs>
  </React.StrictMode>
  , document.getElementById('root'));
```

I don't know why I can't get it to work on **CodePen** when my workstation is working fine.

My parent component is **MyTabset** my children component is **MyTabPanel**.

I will need your help on the following points:

- In my parent component, *renderAppBarTab* method, I want to retrieve the properties of my children component specifically, the label property (today I have set a hard constant because I don't know what to do)? TypeScript does not allow me to call props on my children, because the type of my child parameter does not suit it. I would like to retrieve the properties of the type used for my children component (MyTabPanelProperties).
- I would like to update the hidden property of my children component by modifying the status of my parent component (the value property), as in the example proposed by material-ui.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I kept looking for a solution and found something: https://codepen.io/Answerrer/pen/ExPxmEN.

```
interface MyTabPanelProperties {
  label: string;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}

 type MyTabPanelState = {}

class MyTabPanel extends React.Component<MyTabPanelProperties, MyTabPanelState> {

  render(): JSX.Element {
    const { children, value, index } = this.props;
    const element = (
      <div role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby={'simple-tab'}>
        {children}
      </div>
    );

    return element;
  }
}

interface MyTabsProperties<T = MyTabPanelProperties> {
  selectedTab?: unknown;
  children: React.ReactElement<T> | Array<React.ReactElement<T>> | React.Component<T> | Array<React.Component<T>>;
}

interface MyTabsState {
  selectedTab?: unknown;
}

class MyTabs extends React.Component<MyTabsProperties, MyTabsState> {
  constructor(props: MyTabsProperties) {
    super(props);

    const { children } = this.props;
    const allChilds = React.Children.toArray(children);
    let selectedChildId;

    if (allChilds.length > 0) {
      selectedChildId = (allChilds[0] as MyTabPanel).props.id;
    } else {
      selectedChildId = 0;
    }

    this.state = {
      selectedTab: this.props.selectedTab ? this.props.selectedTab : selectedChildId
    };
  }

  private checkChildrenName(children: ReactNode, names: string | Array<string>): boolean {
    const childs = React.Children.toArray(children);
    let check = false,
        allNames = new Array<string>();

    if (names instanceof Array) {
      allNames = names;
    } else {
      allNames = names.split(' ');
    }

    if (allNames.length === 0) {
      throw Error('Must specify names for check children');
    }

    check = childs.every((child) => {
      let check = false;
      const name = this.getComponentChildName(child);
      if (name) {
        check = allNames.includes(name);
      }
      return check;
    });

    return check;
  }

  private getComponentChildName(component: any): string | undefined {
    const type = (component.type || {});
    let name = undefined;

    if (component) {
      name = component.displayName ||
      component.name ||
      type.displayName ||
      type.name ||
      undefined;
    }

    return name;
  }

  render(): JSX.Element {
    const { children } = this.props;
    let element: JSX.Element;
    if (this.checkChildrenName(children, 'MyTabPanel')) {
      element = (
        <div>
          <AppBar position='static'>
            <Tabs value='0' onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>
              {React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => {
                return this.renderAppBarTab((child as MyTabPanel), index);
              })}
            </Tabs>
          </AppBar>
          {React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => {
            const id = (child as MyTabPanel).props.id;
            if (selectedTab === id) {
              return child;
            }
          })}
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      throw Error('Must use MyTabPanel component in a MyTabs component');
    }
    return element;
  }

  private handleChange(event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, selectedTab: unknown): void {
    this.selectedTab = selectedTab;
  }

  set selectedTab(selectedTab: unknown) {
    this.setState({ selectedTab: selectedTab });
  }

  private renderAppBarTab(child:MyTabPanel, index: number): JSX.Element {
    const { label, id } = child.props;
    const element = (
      <Tab label={label} value={id} />
    );

    return element;
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <MyTabs>
      <MyTabPanel label='Tab1'>
        <Typography>Test1</Typography>
      </MyTabPanel>
      <MyTabPanel label='Tab2'>
        <Typography>Test2</Typography>
      </MyTabPanel>
    </MyTabs>
  </React.StrictMode>
  , document.getElementById('root'));
```

Instead of changing the status of children, in the parent's render, I displayed only the child to be displayed (the one whose identifier corresponds to the selected tab). It works, for the moment. However, there is something I did that I don't really like because I don't understand and I don't know if I have the right to do it (in any case, no compilation error and execution of my project). I had to cast my children. I don't know if I have the right to do this. Could someone clear me up? Do I have the right to cast my child as I did in my case? Thank you